# How to use membership ( user account) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django and need to learn it for a local bot web application.
Usually, modern MVC and MVM web frameworks such as ASP.net core and meteor have simple possibilities and tricks for membership and the user account (especially meteor). But I didn't find anything about this in Django. Does Django has these possibilities or I should download third-party packages?

Comment: What do you mean by "membership"? Are you asking about [managing user accounts, authentication, etc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/)?

Comment: yes I mean the user account.

Comment: Okay, cool. Start by reading the link I provided above.

Comment: You didn't look very hard, since this is well covered in the Django docs.

Answer (score 1):

Django has of course several methods related to user authentication or ACL and so on.
See this 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/

One exemple you can retrive user of request:

```
request.user
```